# Why my Firebase app writes data to the wrong Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I developed a Quasar Vue app with firebase hosting and firestore database. Then my customer created his own (new) Firebase project with me as owner. I deployed the app into this new project. It was successful so far.

But now the prod app is writing data into the firestore of my first developed (dev) project, not into the new firestore target. Also the authentication process links to the old firestore target.

What I'm doing wrong?

My steps so far:

1. For the developing time I set the firebaseConfig settings to my Firebase project.
2. My customer created his own Firebase project and set me as owner.
3. I changed the firebaseConfig to the new project and deployed the app to the new project
4. The app seems to work, but all data actions inclusive the authentication are addressed to the old Firestore target: the new users accounts are created in the wrong target and all data are written to the wrong target.

I can't find any matching solution suggestions and I spent already few days on this issue. So if somebody could help I would really appreciate it.